# setting the lable value of one page from another in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have 2 pages MainPage and MessagePage .

MessagePage  is showed in the TargetName="ContentFrame" of MainPage .

Now I need to set a TextBlock txtblkMsgStatus in MainPage from MessagePage  .

How can I do this ?

**Note:**
MessagePage  is not direcly navigated from MainPage on click of a link button in it.Instead on click of a link button in MainPage , MsgShowPage is rendered in TargetName="ContentFrame" . From MsgShowPage  on click of something else MessagePage  is rendered . So finally MessagePage  gets rendered in TargetName="ContentFrame"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working .. Thanks to code project

[Prism Event Aggregator Service and Extension Methods](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34427/Prism-Event-Aggregator-Service-and-Extension-Metho)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use property changed events on situations like these because you can implement it in many different kinds of custom user controls. Then you would create the event on your messagePage and a handler on your mainpage would do the steps needed when the event is fired. Or if possible you can also use existing events in the messagePage.

For example in your MessagePage:

```
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Private Property m_prop As String
    Public Property Prop As String
        Get
            Return m_prop 
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.m_prop = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Prop")
        End Set
    End Property

Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub
```

And in your MainPage:

```
AddHandler ReportsTreeView.PropertyChanged, _
                AddressOf ChangeHandler

Private Sub ChangeHandler(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Select Case e.PropertyName
            Case "Prop"
               'do something

        End Select

    End Sub
```

Sorry about the VB. You can try for example: http://converter.telerik.com/ to convert to c#.

Comment: I am not getting the access of PropertyChanged in MainPage

Comment: ReportsTreeView is a custom control in my project, replace with your control. Do you create the other page from your mainpage?

Comment: nope , if u see my question . it just renedered in a frame inside a mainpage